# SharpBox[DropBox] Could not retrieve child elements with with GetFolder method

Tags: upload, download, dropbox, sharpbox

I am using sharpbox on .NET 4.5.1, trying to access dropbox and its giving me : Couldn't retrieve child elements from the server.

This happens when I call - var folder = dropBoxStorage.GetFolder("/blah/blah);

When using fiddler to check the request, I get :

19
{"error": "Unauthorized"}
0

-Im not sure what I am doing wrong, but I can get through all the steps and the same code seems to be working on .NET 4 without any problems. I have considered reverting the whole solution to use .NET4 but its giving me an error on the other newget packages that installed.

Is there an alternative way to get a list of folders in my dropbox account. I have set full access to the dropbox app that I created but its still giving me problems.

Comment: There's a potential duplicate question here which pointed at a configuration issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9870751/uploading-to-dropbox-using-sharpbox-api

Comment: I have considered that option, using GetRoot() works, the problem is accessing files inside the App folder which, I have granted full access to my whole dropbox from the app console, but I am still having the same problem.

Comment: I don't have much context on the library you're using, but your code and your app's configuration need to match. If you registered your app for full Dropbox access, there is no app folder, and your code shouldn't be configured to try to access one. I think this library uses the term "sandbox" for the app folder, so don't set that to true in your case, if so. If you do need an app folder, you'll need to register another app.

Comment: I will try that and give an update as soon as possible